# Post a multipart form data using superagent from client side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, superagent

I am trying to use superagent on the client side javascript to make a multipart form post request to my nodejs backend.

Only attach( ) and part( ) method is thorwing the error

My code is as follows:

```
superagent
  .post('/api/audio')
  .attach('file', '/music/music.mp3' )
  .end(function(err, res){
    console.log(res.text);
  });
```

I wrote it according to their documentation http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests but it thorws me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: superagent.post(...).attach is not a function
```

where am i going wrong?

Comment: Did you first declare superagent as a variable by using something like var superagent = require('superagent'); It's basically not identifying superagent as the right object and the first method in the chain is throwing the error. If attach was first it would do the same on attach.

Comment: @nopuck4you I am using superagent on the client side and not in nodejs. even if i try to do var superagent = require('superagent'); it throws an error saying that Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. without that, the other post and get operations are working pretty fine. only attach and part is failing.

Comment: I would need to see your code leading to the superagent call on your first line. Require not being found leads me to believe you're not loading vendor libraries properly into your app because global objects such as Require are not found (if you're using RequireJS, React, or whatever framework that supports Require method). Are you adding superagent directly to your code, if so how?

Comment: i am doing something like this, take a look at this bin http://jsbin.com/hucuri/1/edit?html,js,console,output